# Notepad++ and SFTP connection issue

Tags: ssh, notepad++

I am trying to connect to SFTP server using notepad++ plugin NppFTP. However, while connecting to the remote server I always get below error:

```
Connecting
[SFTP] Connection failed : Timeout connecting to <IP address>
Unable to connect
Disconnected
```

Here are the important configuration details set in NppFTP window for your reference:

```
Port: 22
Connection Type: SFTP
Authentication: Try password authentication
```

I tried to go through some of the solutions stated in few the questions in Stack Overflow but to no avail.

Would really appreciate your suggestions/pointers to resolve this. If it is related to SSH private key, would appreciate if you can provide the steps as well.

**Edit:** I am able to access the server using another FTP tool FileZilla which eliminates any mess with the access front.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out more about where the issue is:

- Can you ping the server you are trying to connect to?

  ping 166.178.233.70
- Did you try connecting with another ftp tool, like FileZilla, that gives more detailed log information?

The possible issues are numerous:

- The ftp server config: set up to exclude connections from certain ip addresses or domains, requires public/private keys...
- Your local connection/VPN is not passing the connection.
  It may require a

Comment: Thank you for responding! I am able to connect to the server using FileZilla but not through notepad++. I just wondering what else I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. The problem was solved after I updated NppFTP.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I changed the wifi connection then, it works.